# Do the word "needed" need a modal in this paragraph?

Tags: modal-verbs

What is the meaning of the last sentence of the following paragraph?

> The preliminary results point to a shift, but more turmoil lies ahead. They portend a sharply polarized parliament divided between pro and anti-Hezbollah lawmakers who will find it difficult to work together to form a new government and *pass the laws **needed** to to enact reforms and begin the country's financial recovery*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing else is required.

> The parliament will find it difficult to pass the laws *which will be*
> needed *if it is* to enact reforms and begin the country's financial
> recovery.

The words which I have added in italics are implied by the context.